# How do I join into a table based on two separate fields on the input and one field on the join table?

Tags: sql

I have two tables like so:

```
Contacts:
+----+----+
|Name| #  |
+----+----+
|Joe | 123|
+----+----+
|Jane| 456|
+----+----+

Calls:
+----+----+
|To  |From|
+----+----+
|123 | 456|
+----+----+
|456 | 123|
+----+----+
```

I need to create a query that returns a table like the following:

```
Log:
+------+------+------+------+
|To    |ToName|From  |FrName|
+------+------+------+------+
|123   | Joe  |  456 | Jane |
+------+------+------+------+
|456   | Jane |  123 | Joe  |
+------+------+------+------+
```

This seems so simple in concept, yet I simply cannot figure out how to piece the SQL together. I have tried nested SELECTS and nested JOINS and just can't get it to run correctly (if at all). Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need to join Calls to two copies of Contacts:

```
SELECT ca.To,
       co1.Name AS ToName,
       ca.From,
       co2.Name AS FrName
FROM Contacts co1 INNER JOIN Calls ca
ON co1.[#] = ca.To INNER JOIN Contacts co2
ON co2.[#] = ca.From
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it [like this (SQL Fiddle)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/930dad/3)

```
SELECT c.to AS "To",
       t.name AS "ToName",
       c.from AS "From",
       f.name AS "FromName"
  FROM Calls c
  JOIN Contact AS t ON t.number = c.to
  JOIN Contact AS f ON f.number = c.from
 ORDER BY 1
;
```